# SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Phpmailer error

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, sendmail

Here is my file, contact-form.php (code)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{

$message=
'Full Name: '.$_POST['fullname'].'<br />
Subject:    '.$_POST['subject'].'<br />
Phone:  '.$_POST['phone'].'<br />
Email:  '.$_POST['emailid'].'<br />
Comments:   '.$_POST['comments'].'
';
    require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"; //include phpmailer class

    // Instantiate Class  
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  

    // Set up SMTP  
    $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
    $mail->Port = 465;  //Gmail SMTP port
    $mail->Encoding = '7bit';

    // Authentication  
    $mail->Username   = "youremail@gmail.com"; // Your full Gmail address
    $mail->Password   = "yourpassword"; // Your Gmail password

    // Compose
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
    $mail->Subject = "New Contact Form Enquiry";      // Subject (which isn't required)  
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);

    // Send To  
    $mail->AddAddress("recipientemail@gmail.com", "Recipient Name"); // Where to send it - Recipient
    $result = $mail->Send();        // Send!  
    $message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';      
    unset($mail);

}
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>

        <div style="margin: 100px auto 0;width: 300px;">
            <h3>Contact Form</h3>
            <form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                      <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" />
                      <br />
                      <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
                      <br />
                      <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
                      <br />
                      <input type="text" name="emailid" placeholder="Email" />
                      <br />
                      <textarea rows="4" cols="20" name="comments" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
                      <br />
                      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
                    </fieldset>
            </form>
            <p><?php if(!empty($message)) echo $message; ?></p>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It Shows this error,
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

I know there are several times this question is asked here but nothing is worked for me,
I tried every previous tricks given here, Please anyone there can help me out.
Exact where is the error n my coding...

Comment: Try TLS with the port 587. Or your web hosting blocked you to connect a third-party SMTP host?

Comment: So you read all those questions and still you're running an old and vulnerable version of PHPMailer, and you've based your code on an obsolete example, and have not read the docs linked from just about every question on this subject. Not impressed.

Answer (score 1):

Please use TLS and port 587 for gmail

```
Set up SMTP  
$mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization    
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";      // Connect using a TLS connection  
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
$mail->Port = 587;  //Gmail SMTP port
$mail->Encoding = '7bit';
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the below points and implemet according to this

Port 25, 465, or 587
SSL/TLS optional.
One or more static IP addresses are required.

Port 465 (SSL required)
Port 587 (TLS required)
Dynamic IPs allowed

Port 25
TLS not required
Dynamic IPs allowed
Mail can only be sent to Gmail or G Suite users

ref :- [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)

just paste this line your code and see what is the exact error . If it is again the SMTP error just follow above .

Ref :- [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)